# How should change the ID of DIV in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have to swap the div.

Swapping is working fine( I am using Jquery Swap Plugin for that).
After swap I want to swap the ID of DIVs too.

Please find JQuery Code. Kindly help me out how should I swap the DIV IDs.

```
 $(".arrowIMG").click(function() {
                    var arr = this.id.split("_");
                    if(arr[0] == 'down'){

                        var div1 = $('#'+'div_' +arr[1]);
                        var next = (parseInt(arr[1]) + 1);
                        alert(next)
                        var div2 = 'div_' + next;

                        div1.swap({
                        target: div2, 
                        opacity: "0.5",
                        speed: 1000, 
                        callback: function() { 
                         //Now Here i want to swap the id of div (div1 and dev2)

                        }
                    });

                    }else if(arr[0] == 'up') {
                        alert('up');
                    }

                });
```

Kindly help me out the way to swap the DIV IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what the desired behavior of your function is - but the following should work to change an ID:

```
$(element).attr('id', 'new_id');
```

Comment: +1 for teaching the fishing skill instead of giving the fish.

Answer (score 1):

```
callback: function() { 

    var div2selector = $('#'+div2); //making both selectors in same format as div2='div_' + next
    var tempid = div1.attr('id');
    div1.attr('id',div2selector.attr('id'));
    div2selector.attr('id',tempid );

                    }
```

EDIT:

div1 and div2 are not in same format. so made similar

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements.

Check this:

```
<div id="my" > s,dfsd </div>  

<div id="src" class="div1">       
    src
</div>
<div id="dest" class="div2">
    dest
</div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$("#my").attr('id','mynewid');
$("#mynewid").html("this new content");

var temp = $(".div1").attr('id');
$(".div1").attr('id',$(".div2").attr('id'));
$(".div2").attr('id', temp);
```

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niranjankala/5Nw8Y/1/)

Adjust your click event behavior using this code snippet. in your function() code you have already accessed those elements so you can directly access the id of those elements.

```
var temp = div1.attr('id');
    div1.attr('id',div2.attr('id'));
    div2.attr('id', temp);
```